# Get exit status of last executed command in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, unix

Is there something like Unix's `echo $?` in Windows?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the errorlevel environment variable:

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

This [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line) has more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

On Powershell you can use:

```
$LastExitCode
```

variable.